# Can a Truth window operator arm be *repaired* (not replaced)?

Tags: windows

Good Afternoon,

In the picture you are looking at "left orientated" Truth window operator arm:

[image]

https://ibb.co/8sBW6Sp

For those of you who are more experienced handymen, will notice that the round plastic bit broke off at the end of the operator arm, resulting in coming out of the rails.

*****My question is:  Do I have to now go and spend $30 to replace the entire arm?  is there no way I can just replace the white plastic bit?*****

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Edited for you, to put picture in post.

Comment: Unfortunately it is probably simpler and cheaper these days to replace the arm.  If you know the shape and size of plastic piece, might be able to have it made by a 3D printer, or might find something at a store/online that might be able to replaced it with.  Depends if the brass looking knob can be removed.

Comment: @crip659 I had not thought about a 3D printer, I know HP made some metal filled setups and they printed us some 6” crescent wrenches that was 10 years ago and I still have mine somewhere it has been used a few times so printing may work but replacement is probably a better path. +

Comment: As someone with a lathe, I'd sure give it a go to turn a replacement out of brass, and forgo the plastic piece completely.   Sure it'll cost $60 in brass and 12 hours, but still a cheaper hobby than smoking :)

Answer (score 1):

Those arms are not really meant to be repaired. The axle is riveted onto the arm so your only real chance of repairing it it to pop the riveted area on the bottom of the arm and pry the piece off. Then look for a nylon washer at your home store that's close to the size of the broken piece, reassemble and Press fit or hammer the riveted part of the axle back into the arm.

You could also try to replace that axle with a bolt, nylon washer and nut on the bottom.

Honestly though, having tried all of the above, I would buy the new part if it's available.

Comment: They may be able to tap a short shoulder bolt but I agree it may be able to be done but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL THE COMMENTS